# Packaging Shared Sql Scripts

Tags: sql-server, nuget-package

Need help on a strategy to push `SQL scripts` into `NuGet` without breaking existing builds.

Have a class library solution which is shared by multiple different solutions.

```
Common

Common\Members\Database\Scripts\

Common\Members\DAL Class Library Project\


Website A

Website B
```

I want to package the SQL underneath `\Database\Scripts\` into NuGet and when the SQL Scripts package is restored in Website A and Website B, the SQL is extracted back into the `\Common\Members\Database\Scripts\` folder.

If I can't achieve this, all our DB tools and CI/CD processes will fail drastically.

How do I achieve this in my `.nuspec file`??

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: All I have is a nuspec with packaging "*.sql" from the \Members\Database\Scripts\ location.